# Sqoop multiple jobs invokation

Tags: java, mapreduce, hdfs, sqoop

I am creating an import tool based on Sqoop, my shell script looks like :

```
while <cond> ; do
sqoop import <parameters> &
done
```

The first invokation works fine but i get the following error for the rest :

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal
>   representation

When I launch each iteration manually one by one, they work fine, but not as mentioned above.

What I found after investigation, is the first sqoop job create the files `QueryResult.java` and `QueryResult.jar`, then next jobs use the same `jar` file which does not reflect the correct type mapping for them.

Can anyone confirm my thought or I missed something ? Does there any easier option to get rid of that, or i have to create seperate `--bindir` for each invokation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name of jar file is determined by class name which is further determined by below parm -

```
--class-name=SCHEMA_TBL_NAME
```

You should include this parm in Sqoop command and pass it different values for different imports.

"." should not be used in this parm value as that will create a sub-dir because "." indicates sub-package in java.